# How to block hacker access if detecting unknown GET in Django Middleware

Tags: django, middleware

I have block IP implemented in middleware, but it's not good enough. Since I know my url, is it possible to block invalid access of my site if detecting 'access', which is not defined in url.py?

I see the probing of site like followings:

```
"GET xyz.cfg/ HTTP/1.1" 500 274 "-" "lib....f33"
"CONNECT www.cnn.com:443 HTTP/1.0" 400 184 ")))"
```

Since this is not access url defined in site, I am thinking to detect such access and deny access by sending:

```
class BlockHackingMiddleware(object):

  def process_request(self, request):

    # How to detect invalid access here?

    return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>Forbidden</h1>')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "block"? You are not blocking anything. You simply return a 403 Forbidden response instead of a 404.

Comment: I mean deny access for such client's request. If such client send valid request, it's ok. But if probing the site, just deny it: make such client 'feel' the site is broken or not working.

Comment: I think a reverse proxy server should do those blocking.

Comment: How to configure/implement in reverse proxy server in nginx?

Comment: Use fail2ban with Nginx. You can temporarily ban an IP address if it's sending some malformed requests or depending on the User-Agent of the client. Here's a tutorial: https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security/

Comment: You could look into modsecurity on an Apache web server.  This is a web application firewall and you can configure that with your known good routes.  the webserver then blocks or rather does not process the bad stuff.  It's another tech to deploy though.